# where is the '__path__' comes from

Tags: python

i can't find who defined  the `'__path__'`,why `'__path__'` can be use.

```
import os
import sys
import warnings 
import ConfigParser # ConfigParser is not a virtualenv module, so we can use it to find the stdlib

dirname = os.path.dirname

distutils_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(ConfigParser.__file__), 'distutils')
if os.path.normpath(distutils_path) == os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath(__file__)):
    warnings.warn(
        "The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?")
else:
    __path__.insert(0, distutils_path)#who defined me.???
    exec open(os.path.join(distutils_path, '__init__.py')).read()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really need to read some Python documentation and learn the basics of the language.

I checked, and you seem to speak Chinese.  Here are Python documentation resources in Chinese:

http://www6.uniovi.es/python/doc/NonEnglish.html#chinese

Now, to answer your question.  I wasn't sure what the answer was, so I used Google.  I did a Google search for "`Python __path__`" and very quickly found:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

> 6.4.3. Packages in Multiple Directories
>
> Packages support one more special
>   attribute, `__path__`. This is
>   initialized to be a list containing
>   the name of the directory holding the
>   package’s `__init__.py` before the code
>   in that file is executed. This
>   variable can be modified; doing so
>   affects future searches for modules
>   and subpackages contained in the
>   package.
>
> While this feature is not often
>   needed, it can be used to extend the
>   set of modules found in a package.

Comment: the first 3 lines looks like better suited for a comment.

Comment: For being such a basic feature of the language, the documentation for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/contents.html) - for example - is not very forthcoming in terms of offering a formal definition for `__path__`.  This is a valid question, that I had as well after doing my due diligence on searching for the answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following description of the __path__ variable:

> It is initialized to a list of one
>   item, containing the directory name of
>   the package (a subdirectory of a
>   directory on sys.path). Changing
>   __path__ changes the list of directories that are searched for
>   submodules of the package.

here: http://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages.html

That page discusses 'built-in package support' in Python 1.5, but it might still apply.

I can't tell you more because I don't use Python. I found this link with a Google search.

EDIT: Yes! I was going to remind you about what we discussed [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997795/what-is-the-decimal-getcontext-copy-mean) but a good start will be to read steveha's Chinese Python documentation.